# Sending email using php mail function

Tags: php

I am sending emails using php's mail function. Some addresses in email clients such as aol, hotmail.com and msn are not receiving it. Gmail works fine! I find it strange as it can pass through Gmail but not others:

```
$semi_rand = md5(time());
$mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x"; 

$headers = "From: $from";
$headers .= "\r\nMIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" .
         "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\r\n" .
         " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";
```

And then I am sending email using:

```
$ok = @mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

For diagnostic purposes `$header` string contains:

```
From: xxx@example.com
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
boundary="==Multipart_Boundary_xd31b2fcd6941ba77b38f866330c24944x"
```

and the `$message` string contains:

```
This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
--==Multipart_Boundary_x0dde39863d56158409aa962fc1dd9a3bx
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

The email message appears here

--==Multipart_Boundary_x0dde39863d56158409aa962fc1dd9a3bx
Content-Type: {"application/octet-stream"};
name="afile.pdf"
Content-Disposition: attachment;
filename="afile.pdf"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

The attachment's contents here

--==Multipart_Boundary_x0dde39863d56158409aa962fc1dd9a3bx
```

Comment: Do all of the emails have actual message content?

Comment: See **Related** column of this site (it's located to the right of your post). All your answers are there.

Comment: The emails have actual message content.

Comment: have u check send email without header, it's send or not?

Comment: Yes I have tried without header and problem still persists.

Answer (score 0):

> Some addresses in email clients such as aol, hotmail.com and msn are not receiving it

Your code is not the best place to start investigating this - check your email logs and bounce messages in the first place. The most likely cause is that your email is being flagged as a spam. You could verify this by setting up a mailbox yourself and sending mesages to it. How to prevent your emails being flagged as spam is a question which has been asked and answered here many times.

> I am not sure whether the header is correct

It would have been mkore helpful to see an example of the email and headers generated (trimed down to a sensible size).

Comment: I setup an aol email account and dont receive messages to it. Nothing in spam folder either. PHP does not throw an error on send and no errors in email error logs either. I am clueless.

Comment: I have posted the `$header` string in the question now.

Comment: @dr_rk - you are still thinking about the problem in terms of your code - I didn't ask what $header was - I asked wht the headers were.

Comment: I havent understood your question, what do you mean by "what the headers are"?